# The animation scroll to top button does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

a couple of days ago i started working with my companies website. I saw it was missing something so I decided to make a scroll to top button with animation. I am a noob in programming so i decided to look on the Internet. There I found [this](https://codepen.io/rdallaire/pen/apoyx) example. I literally copied the whole code but it does not work.

the button in the html:

```
<a href="javascript:" id="return-to-top"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>
```

and this is the jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {        
        $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(200);    
    } else {
        $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(200);   
    }
});
$('#return-to-top').click(function() {      
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop : 0                       
    }, 500);
});
```

I dont know what the problem is because it works on the codepen. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is using jQuery, did you implement the jQuery CDN into your head tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information but if you use the same code from codepen then maybe you need to include jQuery into your site header. (https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this :

```
$('#return-to-top').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();      
$('body, html').stop().animate({
    scrollTop : 0                       
}, 500);
});
```

And first of all, check if you have include jQuery :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" 
integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using?

Anyway, `$(window).scrollTop(0);` seems to be **supported by all browsers**, but if you want to animate the scroll, `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},500);`, like you're using, if you can share your **HTML and CSS code**, maybe the problem is in the **z-index** or try to put the **width** and the **height** of the ".icon-chevron-up" also to the "#return-to-top".

Everything seems to be working, try to use the `console.log('some string here');` to see if the code is running.

Also, check if you added the [jquery](http://jquery.com/) script:
`script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" 
integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Hope you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a lot of people were telling me to include the jquery library. I did add the library before but after I checked the answers I noticed that I added the wrong library. So now its fixed thanks a lot guys.